# Grails DataSource Exception

Tags: grails, datasource

I have an application in production that that recently had a MySQL timeout, so I am trying to add extra parameters to the datasource to prevent this. In the [1.3.7 documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3%20The%20DataSource) it shows that I can add a properties value like so:

```
properties {
        maxActive = 50
        maxIdle = 25
        minIdle = 5
        initialSize = 5
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
        maxWait = 10000
        validationQuery = "/* ping */"
    }
```

However, when I add this to my development datasource I get the following error:

```
 ERROR Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.grails.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer.doStart(InlineExplodedTomcatServer.groovy:112)
    at org.grails.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer$doStart.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:97)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:33)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'maxActive' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 25 more
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why is this a new question and not a comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260365/grails-and-mysql-connection-exception ?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith - Seemed like a different problem. First one was "why am I getting this error?" and this one is more like "when adding these parameters, why am I getting this [other] error?" In any case, do you know the answer? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was testing this locally, so I put the properties in my `development` block. However, I didn't add `pooled = true` since it usually isn't in this section. This was causing the error. Once I added the pooling statement everything worked correctly.

Comment: Right - pooling is important, otherwise you slow performance by waiting for a new connection each time. It may be possible to set those properties in the DriverManagerDataSource you get when not pooling, but there isn't a standard naming convention for those properties, so they're different for each impl. For example using a C3P0 pool would also fail since some of the names are the same but others aren't.

Comment: @Burt Beckwith - Your help has been invaluable. As you can see I still have a lot to learn. Do you have a top recommended resource for Grails (book, video, etc)? I have read through the documentation but I guess I miss a lot that I have to come back to. In any case, thanks for all of your help thus far (and likely in the future).